# Is there a way to disable the "Save" option on a downloadable file, and only allow the "Open/Run" option?

Tags: file, sharepoint, browser, download, save

I have an InfoPath form that sits on my SharePoint site. When the file is clicked in the SharePoint directory, the user is usually given the option to Save or Open the file (sometimes dependent on the browser). Saving the file is frowned upon because I want to ensure that the user is using the latest version of the InfoPath form from the SharePoint location.

In a general web sense, is there a way to disallow a user (or at least attempt to prevent a user) from saving the file, and only opening it? I'm not talking about automatically downloading the file when they click it, as I know this is a security problem, and the reason why the open/save prompt exists in the first place. But can a prompt that only allows them to "Open" a downloaded file be shown instead?

And if not in a general web sense, can this be accomplished somehow using SharePoint black magic? I know that single-clicking a file in SharePoint (depending on the list or directory you're looking at) can sometimes result in that file just being opened in its native application without any prompt to the user whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmmm, I'm not sure if this will help but try creating a hyperlink to your form using this format:

> https://sharepoint/YourSite/_layouts/FormServer.aspx?XsnLocation=https:sharepoint/YourSite/YourLibrary/Forms/template.xsn&Source=https://sharepoint/YourSite&DefaultItemOpen=1

This will open the form without the open/save dialog box

Comment: With a few modifications, this worked!
Since the domain where the link existed, and the domain where the form existed were different, I couldn't use the Source argument to redirect back to the original link page.
I instead put a redirection page on the same SharePoint domain where the form exists, then set the source argument to _that_ URL.
Now, the form opens without a prompt, and when closed, the user is redirected via the Source argument to a SharePoint page that then redirects the user cross-domain back to the original page with the link.
Headache solved.